# iOS font names: dashes versus no dashes

Tags: ios, ipad, uifont

I have found that Core Graphics wants different font names than what UIFont accepts.

For instance, CG accepts "Helvetica Bold" but not "Helvetica-Bold", whereas UIFont is the reverse.

Is there any comprehensive list of fonts available online that clarifies what names are appropriate for each context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code from [this link](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/) but tightened. It's only for for `UIFont`:

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"----------------");
    NSLog(@"FAMILY: %@", familyName);
    for(NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", fontName);
    }
}
```

but these names seem to work fine for `CGFontRef` too, so use (for instance):

```
CGContextSelectFont (context, "Didot-Bold", FONT_SIZE, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
```

of course you can use `font.fontName.UTF8String` to get from a `UIFont`....

Answer (score 1):

The font name used by UIFont depends on the creator of the Font. Sometimes a font name for italic will end with `Ita` and sometimes `-Italic` - there is no clear naming rule for that.
I came up with an implementation that handles all the differences and returns you the right UIFont for all font-family + font style combinations - so you don't have to hardcode the font name.
You can see it at http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/26/uifont-from-a-css-definition/

With the code I provide there, you can get your desired UIFont as easy as:

`UIFont *myFont = [FontResolver fontWithDescription:@"font-family: Helvetica; font-size:17px; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;"];`